# How to drop foreign key using a subselect?

Tags: mysql

First off, we're using MySQL 5.

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
SET @fkcn = (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
             WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = (SELECT DATABASE())
               AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = "ProviderOrder");
ALTER TABLE AuditProviderOrder
    DROP FOREIGN KEY @fkcn,
    DROP COLUMN ProviderOrderID;
```

But MySQL 5 complains that it's invalid syntax. I've tried `DROP FOREIGN KEY (SELECT @fkcn)` as well as inlining `@fkcn` with similar syntax issues.

Is there a way to fully automating retrieving the foreign key name for use in the `DROP FOREIGN KEY` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the entire `DROP` statement into a string that you execute with `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

```
SET @drop = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE AuditProviderOrder
    DROP FOREIGN KEY ', @fkcn, ',
    DROP COLUMN ProviderOrderID');
PREPARE stmt FROM @drop;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use a variable in the `DROP FOREIGN KEY`, but you can construct a dynamic sql statement and execute it.

```
SET @fkcn = (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
            WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = (SELECT DATABASE())
              AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = "ProviderOrder");

SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE AuditProviderOrder DROP FOREIGN KEY ', @fkcn);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```